# How to exectute XML script file from a command line (Windows)

Tags: xml

```
    @echo off
    set PATH=../../tools/bin/Python26;../../tools/bin;%PATH%
    if %1!==! goto build_with_param
    set arg1=%1
    "filearchiver" make_xml/%1_create.xml
    "filearchiver" xml/%1_create.xml
    echo "Done"
    goto end
    :build_with_param
    set /p id="Enter File to make: " %=%
    "filearchiver" make_xml/%id%_create.xml
    "filearchiver" xml/%id%_create.xml > output.txt
    echo "Done"
    pause
    :end
    echo "Finished Execution"
```

-This is my execution file
-make_xml file contains some xml commands like :
bgm_create.xml

```
<ScriptFile>
    <CreateEterPackXml Input="source/bgm:bgm/" ArchivePath="../bin/pack/bgm" XmlPath="xml/bgm_create.xml"></CreateEterPackXml>
```

-So basically I have 30 XML files to execute.How can i do that with that command.It does not work.